# Pentaho Snowflake plugin

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pentaho-data-integration

I have installed the snowflake plugin in my Pentaho version 9.2. I have specific flows with me that I need to update. Those flows are working fine then suddenly they start showing errors. enter. [find this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7YCP.png) Error is in the table input step.

> Table input.0 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from
> 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Unexpected error

```
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at java.lang.Thread.run (null:-1)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run (RunThread.java:62)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow (TableInput.java:143)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery (TableInput.java:265)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow (Database.java:2712)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow (Database.java:2734)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow (Database.java:2756)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet (DatabaseMeta.java:3030)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.database.BaseDatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet (BaseDatabaseMeta.java:2138)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getValueFromResultSet (ValueMetaBase.java:5309)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBaseResultSet.getTimestamp (SnowflakeBaseResultSet.java:302)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeResultSetV1.getTimestamp (SnowflakeResultSetV1.java:236)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -  at net.snowflake.client.core.SFBaseResultSet.getTimestamp (SFBaseResultSet.java:522)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 - 
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2764)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2734)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2712)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:265)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:143)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at net.snowflake.client.core.SFBaseResultSet.getTimestamp(SFBaseResultSet.java:522)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeResultSetV1.getTimestamp(SnowflakeResultSetV1.java:236)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBaseResultSet.getTimestamp(SnowflakeBaseResultSet.java:302)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaBase.getValueFromResultSet(ValueMetaBase.java:5309)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.BaseDatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet(BaseDatabaseMeta.java:2138)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.getValueFromResultSet(DatabaseMeta.java:3030)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getRow(Database.java:2756)
2022/06/23 20:35:38 - Table input.0 -   ... 6 more
```

also in database connection, the connection type is automatically selected to snowflake database from snowflake. I thought that it can be the cause. Now my all-flows table input step is showing an error.
kindly guide me.

thanks
shivam

Comment: This looks to be more a Pentaho DI issue than a Snowflake one. I'd suggest asking on their vantara community page. Having said that, perhaps try defining your own JDBC connection using this guide: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/configuring-a-jdbc-connection-to-snowflake-using-pentaho

Comment: What kind of SQL statement are you running? The stacktrace shows you're getting a NPE(NullPointerException) from JDBC when retrieving the value of a column that seems to be a Timestamp one. That means you already have a connection but the retrieving the result set is what causes the issue. If you don't know the exact SQL statement, you can try to reproduce and get the SQL statement from query history in Snowflake UI.

Comment: Are you using pentaho community edition ? How did you install snowflake plugin ?

Comment: HI, @P.Phalak yes I m using the community version. I have directly installed from Marketplace

Comment: hi @Sergiu i m using "select * from <tablename>" and the same i m using before . Can you explain like how to solve this issue